# Data too large when trying to aggregate with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a HUGE dataframe of almost 2M rows. The structure is as such:

```
head(df)
         TimeStamp Price Contracts
1 9/29/2014 9:00:03 AM 16.05        10
2 9/29/2014 9:00:03 AM 16.04         1
3 9/29/2014 9:00:06 AM 16.05         2
4 9/29/2014 9:00:07 AM 16.05        11
5 9/29/2014 9:00:07 AM 16.05         1
6 9/29/2014 9:00:07 AM 16.05         1
```

As you can see, there are several timestamps with multiple entries. I am trying to aggregate this df by the timestamps, by taking the weighted average. I am using the dplyr package, and below is the code I am using, with the result:

```
as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(TimeStamp) %>% summarise(VWAP = weighted.mean(Price, Contracts)))
              TimeStamp     VWAP
1 9/29/2014 10:00:08 AM 16.09000
2 9/29/2014 10:00:11 AM 16.09000
3 9/29/2014 10:00:17 AM 16.10012
4 9/29/2014 10:00:18 AM 16.12500
5 9/29/2014 10:00:20 AM 16.15000
6 9/29/2014 10:00:22 AM 16.10000
```

Say WHAAA??? What happened to 9AM data?!?! The result seems to have skipped over the first chunk of the dataframe! So, I took just the first thousand rows, re-ran the aggregation, and the results are below:

```
as.data.frame(head(df, 1000) %>% group_by(TimeStamp) %>% summarise(VWAP = weighted.mean(Price, Contracts)))
             TimeStamp     VWAP
1 9/29/2014 9:00:03 AM 16.04909
2 9/29/2014 9:00:06 AM 16.05000
3 9/29/2014 9:00:07 AM 16.05000
4 9/29/2014 9:00:08 AM 16.05500
5 9/29/2014 9:00:13 AM 16.06000
6 9/29/2014 9:00:20 AM 16.05000
```

There they are!! Whats the deal, here?!?! So, I kept playing with the size of the df. I found that at about 3000 rows, the returned df seems like it begins to write over itself:

```
as.data.frame(head(df, 3100) %>% group_by(TimeStamp) %>% summarise(VWAP = weighted.mean(Price, Contracts)))
> head(tester1)
              TimeStamp     VWAP
1 9/29/2014 10:00:08 AM 16.09000
2 9/29/2014 10:00:11 AM 16.09000
3 9/29/2014 10:00:17 AM 16.10012
4  9/29/2014 9:00:03 AM 16.04909
5  9/29/2014 9:00:06 AM 16.05000
6  9/29/2014 9:00:07 AM 16.05000
```

So it looks as if there is some sort of memory limitation in dply? Is that what is going on? I looked over the documentation and did not find anything ...

Comment: Try `sort(c("9/29/2014 10:00:08",  "9/29/2014 9:00:03"))` and see what you get. Your `TimeStamp` is just a character string rather a real date, thus R just does a lexicographical sort on it. Thus you first see `9/29/2014 10...` time stamps and only then  `9/29/2014 9...` will follow.

Comment: An easy way to spot that it's not a date-time is the `9` in the time (and month).  If it was a time, single digit hours (months) would have  a zero out front, i.e.  `09`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the lubridate and data.table packages.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)
# convert timestamp to a POSIXct object to allow for proper sorting by time
df[ , TimeStamp := mdy_hms(TimeStamp)]
# sort by time
setkey(df, TimeStamp)
# perform weighted mean by Timestamp
df[ , .(VWAP = weighted.mean(Price, Contracts)), by = key(df)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out a solution above (apparently posted about the same time), but I will look into this. This looks much more straightforward. I have never messed with the data.table package, so thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Actually lubridate objects use more memory than the equivalent character objects in this case. If you want your data sorted by date I recommend first sorting using the code above but leaving Timestamp as a character vector if memory is an issue.

Comment: @IanKotliar it's unlikely that data table will be any faster in this case because the bottleneck will be the parsing. Also I don't see how a POSIXct (which is what lubridate produces) would take up more memory than a string, given that a POSIXct is just a double.

Comment: Double requires 8 bytes whereas string requires 4.

Answer (score 2):

Well, thanks to David, I figured it out. The df was being sorted as if it were characters (which they were). So, the df is fine, and I used the following to sort it and get it as I expected. (Feel free to suggest any better  or more elegant methods...)

```
df$TimeStamp <- strptime(df$TimeStamp, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
df<- df[order(df$TimeStamp),]
```

Comment: @IanKotliar nothing really, I'm just being sarcastic.